# How do I stop the previous queued releases without having to cancel them one at a time?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-pipelines-release-task

We have a release pipeline that automatically creates a new release every time a build is completed.

At that point, we have a release candidate, so this makes sense. Every build is potentially releasable.

In the pipeline, the Release goes automatically to dev. So we get a check in and the build and then it goes to the Dev server.

There is an approval gate on the release moving to Stage. The approval usually takes a while and development will continue while waiting for the approval.

Now, we have 10 - 15 builds that are listed as queued.

So, I need to automatically cancel each one in order to start the release of the LATEST build to stage.

Is there a way to automatically cancels a release when a newer version makes it into the queue or should I instead create a POST-approval in the Dev stage that keeps it out of stage until someone hits "go" on that release version?

Am I using this right?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change your deployment queue settings so that only the latest build is eligible for deployment to that environment.

[image]

Comment: You sir, win the internets today! Thank you!