# How to force multiple releases from the same release definition to run sequentially

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am looking for a way to guarantee that if multiple releases are generated using a particular release definition, that they don't run in parallel, but do so sequentially.

I know we can force deployments to specific environments within a release to run sequentially, but I can't find a way prevent any environment within a release from starting if another release from the same release definition is also deploying to some stage.

Is this possible?

Update: this question is different from the other question that is suggested as a duplicate because here I am looking to block *any* environment of other releases from being deployed, while another release is already deploying to *any* other environment, from the same release definition. The suggested duplicate only allows control to a specific environment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I stop the previous queued releases without having to cancel them one at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54912243/how-do-i-stop-the-previous-queued-releases-without-having-to-cancel-them-one-at). This isn't exactly the same scenario, but it's close.

Comment: @Daniel, thank you, but unfortunately that's different. I updated my question to make it clearer. I want to prevent deployment to *any* environment, if another release from the same release definition is already deploying to *any* environment.

Comment: Okay, that's fair. Why is that a need?

Comment: Different environments in each release impact the same resource in different ways or different components of the resource, but it's not possible for those actions to happen simultaneously on that resource. Also the whole thing is automated, so we end up creating new releases each time a change needs to be made. So I am exploring what my options might be.